# How to show one sub Flatlist in one main flatlist?

Tags: react-native, expo, flatlist

I've products list(main list) which have some categories like mobile, screen guards, covers, neckbands, etc. In screen guards and covers category, we have phone list to show which product in it(Sub list). So that's I want to show the sub list.

Below is my code:

My data appears like this: https://jsonkeeper.com/b/9YH3

Code:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  let tok = authContext.user;
  let id = authContext.userid;
  axios
    .post(
      url.productlist,
      qs.stringify({
        fcm_token: tok,
        sort: 1,
        user_id: id,
        page: 1,
      }),
      {
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        },
      }
    )
    .then((response) => {
      setProducts(response.data.products);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log("Something Went Wrong : " + err);
    });
}, []);
```

And the FlatList code is below:

```js
<FlatList
  data={products}
  keyExtractor={item => item.id.toString()}
  renderItem={({ item }) =>
  // list items appears here
  }
/>
```

Comment: why not use `sectionList`?

Comment: yes, tried it but data isn't appear on user side.